# Detail on deploying an Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, hosting, web-deployment

I'm noob about hosting and have no idea about servers as well. I'm keen to learn on own, so my doubts are

> 1. Hosting a Rails App? (is it possible - cost free ) and how and where to start with ..
> 2. Best server to host Rails App? (I've heard about heroku)

***Space on server** and other things I need to know that are necessary to host an app?*

Explanations in simple way to get me going ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think heroku is a great place to start.  There is a free tier that is adequate for learning. [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605316/detail-on-deploying-an-rails-application/21605478#21605478)  AWS also has free tiers but it will take a bit more work

Comment: Heroku will definitely make your life a lot easier.  I remember the first time i deployed anything onto a real server and it was extremely daunting.  Heroku makes it much more step-by-step and also takes care of a lot of the sys admin stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a google search seems to be the best way to find out, I found this guys:
https://www.openshift.com/
https://www.digitalocean.com/ (not free but reasonable cost)
you already found heroku ;)